# Converting SAS to Python

Tags: python, pandas, sas

I'm converting a program of SAS code into a python equivalent. One section that i'm struggling with is how to convert a macro program in SAS when the variables used within the macro are used to create a dataset. for example:

```
%macro program(type);
data portfolio_&type.;
set portfolio;
run;
```

I basically want to create a dataframe equivalent of portfolio_&type. Any idea how I proceed with this?

Edit: I don’t think I have enough detail originally

Say my data has a column called type, and that takes either value of ‘tree’ or ‘bush’, I want to split my data in two, and then process the same functions on both and create separate output tables for both. In SAS this is quite simple. I write macros which are effectively functions that take my arguments and drop them into the code, making them unique datasets.

```
%macro program(type);
data portfolio_&type.;
set portfolio (where=(type=&type.));
run;


Proc freq data=Portfolio_&type.;
Tables var1/out=summary_&type.;
Run;
%mend;
%program(Tree);
%program(bush);
```

The & allows me to drop my text into the dataset name but I can’t do this with a def function type statement in python because I can’t drop the argument into my data frame name

Comment: Could you expand on what this code does exactly? I don't know SAS, only Python. Please [edit] to clarify (body *and* title please). There's some related tips on this Meta question: [How should we tag code translation questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265825/4518341) and [ask] has tips on writing a good title.

Comment: Sure. Say I have a data frame where one of the columns is called type which is categorical. I want to make a separate data frame for one of the category’s in that column, and then do a set of other functions on it, and then repeat for a different category. SAS allows you to do this with macros and suffix your datasets with the category but I can’t seem to replicate that in python

Comment: OK, this might be going over my head (still learning Pandas myself), but it sounds like you want something like `df.groupby('type').apply(other_function)`. Is that close?

Comment: Not quite. Once I have my data frames I can process the other functions but my problem is slightly different but I’ll add to my original question

Answer (score 0):

Your SAS macro wants to dynamically name the SAS dataset fed into PROC Freq. pandas dataframes cannot be named dynamically. You need to use the resolved macro variable value Portfolio_Tree and Portfolio_bush as the dataframe names. SAS dataset names are case-insensitive and pandas dataframe are case-sensitive.

For PROC FREQ you would then you would have,
Portfolio_Tree[‘var1’].value_counts

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).